# Using the result of fn:floor() in a xsl:for-each range

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm using XSLT 2.0 (Saxon) and am trying use the result of a `floor()` call as the upper bound to the range in a `<xsl:for-each>` loop.

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to floor(string-length($input_string) div 2)">...</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm getting the error message:

> XPTY0004: Required item type of second operand of 'to' is xs:integer;
>   supplied value has   item type xs:decimal

I'd have thought that the resulting type of `floor()` would be an integer, but this seems to imply that floor will return a decimal if supplied a decimal: [http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.8/functions.html#fn:floor](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.8/functions.html#fn%3afloor)

How do I get an integer so I can use it in my range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `select="1 to xs:integer(floor(string-length($input_string) div 2))"`, of course your stylesheet then needs to declare `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

If continue to have problems the please tell us which Saxon version you use, the first to support XSLT 2.0 as specified in 2007 was Saxon 8.9, the current version is 9.5.

Comment: I didn't realise you could "cast" expressions like that - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
select="1 to ($input_string idiv 2)"
```

though I would need to check the spec to be confident that this returns the same answer in all circumstances.